# Как закрыть окно рекламы после просмотра? Unity Ads

Tags: c#, unity3d

Доброго времени суток!

Хотел сделать в своём приложении так, чтобы после просмотра рекламы она закрывалась сама (не требовалось нажать на крестик). Но так как я чайник, не знаю как это сделать, поиски в интернете по данной теме меня никуда не привели. В следствии чего, прошу помощи. Возможно ли это сделать и как?

Использую `UnityAds`.